# tcl dom failed due to error "no element found" at line

Tags: xml, tcl, tdom

When i was trying to pare XML content through dom xml parser, i was getting error message like error "no element found", Below error message snippet

```
error "no element found" at line 16458 character 2 "ctivate-all -1/1

PA"
     "dom parse $xmlResp"
    (procedure "::Client::xmlToHtml" line 8)
    invoked from within "::Client::xmlToHtml"
    invoked from within "set res [::Client::xmlToHtml]"
    (file "TestReturnXML.tcl" line 32)
```

In Client procedure, I was doing

```
set xmlFileId [open logs/xml/XmlReturn.xml]
set xmlResp [read $xmlFileId]
set indoc [dom parse $xmlResp]
```

Could you explain why i am getting this error message, any reasons ?However i have escaped all XML content in my inputted XML file.

And also could you explain what are different situation will get this error message.

Thanks
Malli

Comment: The root cause is i have used same named file for both xml reading at a time due to this i am getting this error message.